# How do I throw polymorphically?

Tags: c++, oop, exception

class MyExceptionBase { };

```
    class MyExceptionDerived : public MyExceptionBase { }; 

        void f(MyExceptionBase& e) 
        {
     // ... throw e; 
        }  

        void g()
        { 
           MyExceptionDerived e;
         try{ 
              f(e);
             }
         catch (MyExceptionDerived& e)
         {
          ...code to handle MyExceptionDerived... 
         }
        catch (...)
        {
           ...code to handle other exceptions... 
        } 
    }
```

If you try this,  at run-time when your catch (...) clause is entered, and not your catch (MyExceptionDerived&) clause,what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`throw` conceptually throws a copy of the exception object. Since you're throwing through the function `f()`, you're slicing a copy of `MyExceptionBase` and throwing that.

note: *always* derive your exception base from either `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`.